# (Django) How to assign the username of current user to some other model in a view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I want to assign the username field of Passengers model to the username of the current logged in user. I cant seem to do it. Below is the code.

Models.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

        user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username

class Passengers(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        passenger_firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        passenger_lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        passenger_age = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        passenger_gender =  models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='female')
```

froms.py

```
class PassengerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Passengers
        fields = (
        'passenger_firstname',
        'passenger_lastname',
        'passenger_age',
        'passenger_gender')
```

views.py

```
def passenger_info(request):

    if request.method == "POST":

        passenger_details = PassengerForm(data=request.POST)

        if passenger_details.is_valid():
            passenger_details.username = request.user
            passenger_details.save()

    else:
        passenger_details = PassengerForm()

    return render(request,'passenger_info.html',{'passenger_details':passenger_details})
```

No error message is printed out but it leaves the username field blank like below:

[django-admin model object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JMB1.png)

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any of this. Just have a ForeignKey from Passenger to User.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. But, whats the one line of code that assign the passenger.username to the current logged in user's username? Because with present settings, it threw me an error "NOT NULL constraint failed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the answer by @Navid2zp is correct, the other issue you're having is with this line:

```
passenger_details.username = request.user
```

`passenger_details` is a `ModelForm`, and after initialisation it doesn't have an attribute `username`. It has a field `username` that can be accessed as bound field (`passenger_details['username']`) if the form has `data` or as a form field (`passenger_details.fields['username']`).

By giving it the attribute `username` you're achieving nothing since that won't be associated in any way with the field `username`.

But the easiest way to assign additional parameters to the instance of the form before it is saved is the following:

```
profile = passenger_details.save(commit=False)  # gives you the instance
profile.user = request.user  # assuming you're using `ForeignKey` here, calling it `user` instead of `username` for clarity
profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it doesn't make any sense to do it like this. You should create a ForeignKey to user model.

Also `request.user` will return the user object not the username so if you need the username you should call it: `request.user.username`

And to fix your problem:

```
class Passengers(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False)
    passenger_firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    passenger_lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    passenger_age = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    passenger_gender =  models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='female')
```

also you can get the first name and the last name from User model too. also gender and age should be in `UserProfileInfo` model which makes more sense and `Passengers` model should be about linking users to bus, airplane or etc not to hold data that are not going to change.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried with request.user.username and making that a ForeignKey but that doesn't solve the problem. Again, the username field is remaining blank and since it has null = False this time, it threw me an error "NOT NULL constraint failed".

Comment: If you change the username field to foreignkey then you should go with `request.user`. Basically `request.user` returns the user objects which a field like foreignkey will accepts. And if you need just the username string then you should call it with `request.user.username`

Comment: I have changed the Passenger Model according to your code. And also i have this: 'passenger_details.username = request.user'. It shows error: NOT NULL constraint failed/

Comment: As i explained: `request.user` will return the user object not the username. you should get the  username like this: `request.user.username`